# What rtmp streaming software solutions exist?

Tags: software-recommendation, streaming, adobe-flash

I've been doing some live streaming lately, and learned that Adobe's [Flash Media Live Encoder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashmediaserver/flashmediaencoder/) is cross-platform. Unfortunately, it's been ludicrously unstable crashing occasionally during use, and always crashing when told to quit.

After searching for alternatives, the closest I came was Telestream's [Wirecast](http://www.telestream.net/wire-cast/overview.htm?icid=homewirecast) product, which despite it's "affordable" claim, is $450 I don't have, and about $400 worth of features I don't need.

What I need in a rtmp/flash streaming client is:

1. Stability and a good native *feeling* client. Adobe's dark-grey drab interface is neither of these things.
2. A reasonable price. I'm willing to pay money, but triple-digits is pushing it. Free is always nice :).
3. Support for XML profile import. I'm unsure of any other specific term for this, but [Nico Nico](http://www.niconico.com/) has a link in their streaming interface to download an XML file containing stream quality parameters, default device selection, and of course the URL of the streaming server. It's wonderful to simply tell FMLE to open this file, and then just click 'Start'.

I have no specific requirements of 'effects' or generally ways to change the stream. I use [CamTwist](http://camtwiststudio.com/) as a front-end device to set the video however I want.

Has anyone used any other software fulfilling this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

Try [influxis.com](https://influxis.com), it's web based but you could get your cam streaming pretty quickly. There are free options also like [Red5](http://red5.org), it's open source and it doesn't use FMS.

Comment: I'm not looking to change stream hosts.

Comment: By which I mean, all of Influxis' apps are free, but there aren't download links, which makes me believe I have to signup and pay for their services first.

Comment: Yes you have to pay something, it's not much though if you want to see something running. But why don't you get Adobe FMS development license and you'll get some examples as well?

Answer (score 1):

3 possible alternatives to using FMLE.

1. [Vidblaster Home](https://www.vidblasterx.com) is another alternative to Wirecast & FMLE.
2. Also, you could go the route of using a hardware encoder like [Hauppauge Stream-ez Pro](http://hauppauge.com/site/products/data_streameez-pro.html).
3. Finally, if your current hosting solution using [Wowza Streaming Engine](https://www.wowza.com/products/streaming-engine) as their server side software, you can utilize a basic IP Camera like the Axis M1025 Network Camera.

Answer (score 1):

I setup nginx with the open source [NGINX-based Media Streaming Server](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) project recently and used [Open Broadcaster Software](https://obsproject.com) to stream to it.

I was able to watch the stream using both Kodi and VLC.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for Influxis the last 4 years and I've learned that FMLE is actually quite stable if configured properly. What version are you using?

Most all versions support XML profiles as well. What are your current settings? (format, frame rate, key frame interval, input size, bit rate etc.)

There's also many adjustments that can be done on the server-side to optimize how the data is written to the network layer specifically for live streaming.

Comment: Using FMLE 2.3 under OS X 10.7 on my MacBook Pro. -

I didn't state that FMLE doesn't support XML profiles, I said that if I use some other app, it must support XML profiles. -

The settings are all provided by Nico Nico, which means that I don't control the settings, nor can I optimize anything server side.

Comment: P.S. Welcome to Ask Different :).

Answer (score 0):

There is crtmpd, which does rtmp streaming for you. Red5 as suggested is another option, as is wowza media server.

If you don't need rtmp but want to use flash player, you can also use http streaming, which nginx does nicely.

Beware that for full interaction, something like fms, red5 or wowza is required, the rest only streams, and that's it.

If you simply want to stream a webcam, check out QuickTime Broadcaster from Apple, combined with darwin streaming server. Both work on OS X. For even simpler options, there is EvoCam and you have options like YouTube Live as well.